# Anaconda Navigator 1.9.7 - Environments - Update Index Error - Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, ubuntu-16.04

I recently updated Anaconda to the most recent release (Anaconda3-2019.03-Linux-x86_64) within Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.  Unfortunately, when I attempt to "Update Index" in the Environments tab, it hangs and never completes.  So, I am not able to make any package updates through A-N.  I did not have this problem with the previous version.  I reviewed the terminal window and found the following error immediately after trying to run "Update Index":

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/heisenberg/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/api/anaconda_api.py", line 674, in _model_data_ready
    data = output[:]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Any idea why this is happening?

I tried to completely removed anaconda and reinstalled to no effect.  However, reverting back to the previous version I was then able to Update Index as expected (just in the old version...)

Receives this error in the terminal window:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/heisenberg/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/api/anaconda_api.py", line 674, in _model_data_ready
    data = output[:]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: I have the same error in the terminal, same unending "Update index...", same Anaconda version. I'm using Fedora 30.